# .pop() and .append() from one list affecting a different list?

Tags: python, list, append

I'm doing some combinatorics stuff in Python and getting a strange effect. I create several lists, pop from one, append the result to the other—but an already-existing entry of a *third* list is somehow being changed.

```
def cycle( theList ):
    cycleList = []
    if len(theList) < 3:
        return theList
    for ii in range( len(theList) - 2 ):
        cycleList.append([ 
                theList[ii],
                theList[ii + 1],
                theList[ii + 2] ])
    return cycleList


Combos = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]]

for combo in Combos:
    listA = []
    listB = []
    fromListA = [x for x in combo]
    fromListB = [fromListA[0]]

    listA.append( cycle(fromListA) )
    listB.append( cycle(fromListB) )

    for jj in range(1, len(combo) - 1):
        print("List B's first entry: " + str(listB[0]) )
        fromListB.append( fromListA.pop( len(fromListA) - 1 ))
        print("List B's first entry: " + str(listB[0]) )

        break
    break
```

Here's the output:

```
>>> execfile('test.py')
List B's first entry: [1]
List B's first entry: [1, 5]
>>>
```

I've been learning C++ lately, so I want to look for a weirdly placed reference or something...

... but this is Python.

Edit: Hot damn! It *is* a reference issue.

To copy a list, one can use

```
listA = list(listB)
```

or

```
listA = listB[:]
```

Comment: Not sure where you're problem is yet, but Python passes lists by reference.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `fromListA.pop( len(fromListA) - 1 )`; you can just do `fromListA.pop()`. `.pop()` defaults to the last item in the list.

Comment: Aah, found it. Answer coming.

Comment: @Cyphase Oh! Two things I didn't know; thank you!

Comment: Sure thing :). Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the `cycle()` function.

```
def cycle( theList ):
    cycleList = []
    if len(theList) < 3:  # <<< PROBLEM IS HERE <<<<<
        return theList  # <<<<< PROBLEM IS HERE <<<<<
    for ii in range( len(theList) - 2 ):
        cycleList.append([ 
                theList[ii],
                theList[ii + 1],
                theList[ii + 2] ])
    return cycleList
```

When you do `fromListB = [fromListA[0]]` in the outer `for` loop, `fromListB` has a length of one. Then when you do `listB.append( cycle(fromListB) )`, `cycle(fromListB)` ends up returning the same list you passed in, so `listB[0]` is now pointing to the same list as `fromListB`.

Now, when you do `fromListB.append( fromListA.pop( len(fromListA) - 1 ))` in the inner `for` loop, you're modifying the same list that `listB[0]` is pointing at.

By the way, the relevant bit is `fromListB.append('ANYTHING')`, not the fact that you're popping from `fromListA`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in line -

```
listB.append( cycle(fromListB) )
```

The cycle function directly returns 'theList' if the length of theList is less than 3. Which is the case for fromListB , hence the first element to ListB is the reference to fromListB , and when you spend to fromListB , it also reflects in ListB's first element .